# override bootstrap variables angular-cli

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, sass, angular-cli

I have an angular-cli project which I have added bootstrap-sass package. I have loaded the styles in angular-cli.json by adding this:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "styles.scss"
      ]
```

But I want to be able to override some of the variables that bootstrap has. How can I do this in a angular-cli project?

Answer (score 4):

This was actually rather easy. If anyone has the same problem what I did was to include the following as global styles instead of loading styles via angular-cli.json:

```
$icon-font-path: '~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/';
@import './shared/styles/_variables'; // my custom vars that overrides bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
```

Comment: In which file you import them?

Comment: Don't have the code in front of me. But it was either the global styles.scss or in my root component.

Answer (score -1):

It should work if you import bootstrap.scss to your main style.scss file in the following way.

```
@import '<RALATIVE_PATH_TO>node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```